# try-finally block: why does the following code work when the finally block is supposed to run before the else block?

Tags: python, flask

I have a website with a Flask backend, and when a particular URL is hit, a file is sent to the user's browser to be downloaded. For server space management, I want the file to be deleted as soon as it's sent to the user to be downloaded, so I added a finally block to delete the file:

```
@app.route('/api/conversions/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
def send_file(filename):
    mimetype_value = 'audio/mp4' if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == '.m4a' else ''
    try:
        return send_from_directory('conversions', filename, mimetype=mimetype_value, as_attachment=True)
    finally:
        delete_file(os.path.join('conversions', filename))
```

The interesting thing is that from what I've read, the `finally` block should be running before the `return` statement, but if that's the case then how is my website working? The file is being sent to the user without any problems, which should be impossible if the `finally` block runs first as I'm deleting the file in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of events in your code is equivalent to this:

```
return_value = send_from_directory(...
delete_file(...
return return_value
```